# Luis Miramontes helped enable the sexual revolution. Why isn’t he better known?

Tags: social-context, chemists, social

> Why, then, did Miramontes remain an obscure figure? He was a student at a time when science was especially hierarchical. And the fact that Searle beat Syntex to market cut Mexico — and Miramontes — out of the narrative. Perhaps renown was not Miramontes’ preference.

<sub>**Source:** Carmen Drahl, [Luis Miramontes helped enable the sexual revolution. Why isn’t he better known?](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/luis-miramontes-chemistry-birth-control-pill-ingredient-sexual-revolution), Science News, September 21, 2021.</sub>

---

I liked the conclusion, but does the fact that he is Mexican, at a time when Latin Americans were (and still are) marginalized in the USA, didn't contribute to this story being erased? I think that an American's voice has always been more powerful than anyone else's, that may have contributed as well. Not to mention the fact that Djerassi himself, one of the directors of the company responsible for the creation of the hormone norethindrone, canceled the participation of the chemist Miramontes from all his writings on the hormone and its creation, citing only him as "a young Mexican chemist" (part cited in the article as well), and what intrigues me is also the fact that many people (mainly feminists who study on the subject) do not know him, or have not heard of his name, even though he played a very important role in history of feminism with the sexual revolution (as stated in the title of the article).

Comment: There are many inventors whose names are not well-known.

Comment: This is a really interesting question but it may be really challenging to put it into a form that fits one of the Stack Exchange sites. The topic is certainly on-topic here; but is there some way to adjust your question to ask for fact-based answers? Since there can be many reasons why a person may not be better known and there could be several at play here, it would be a challenge to converge on a right answer. One way to tackle this would be to break this up into a few shorter question focusing on specific events where things can be verifiable.

Comment: One thought; your linked article says: "Miramontes’ parish priest threatened his wife with excommunication, Miramontes Vidal says — the Catholic Church’s influence in 1960s Mexico can’t be overstated. Miramontes perhaps hinted at this when he wrote that the pill 'generated profound, serious moral questions in some sectors of society, and obtuse, reactionary attitudes in others.'" You could ask for help tracking that quote down and expanding on the context. The impact of Catholic church on the lives of scientist is covered in [many posts](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/search?q=catholic) here!

Comment: I can imagine someone in this position doing everything they could to *avoid being well known* for just this reason alone! (see also [posts with "pope"](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/search?q=pope))